# Can I / How to implement object recognition in app?

Tags: computer-vision, dji-sdk

our aim is to develop an **automotive app which automates and standardizes photo shooting** of newly arrived **cars** at dealership. Basically, our Mavic 2 Pro takes off, orbits the vehicle and shoots photo every 90 degrees and than lands to its original position. The orbiting radius is app 4.5 m.

Since the scene of shooting is small (or when shooting indoor, GPS might not be available), we would like to rely more on built in object recognition as implemented in activetrack missions. We have currently an app based on waypoint mission, but it is not accurate. So my questions are:

1, Can anyone point us in direction how to **implement object recognition in our app**?

2, **If** recognition is **not** available, how to ensure **consistency of output**? While testing, sometimes the output exif info of photos show compass deviation up to 4 degrees, which results in object being out of view.

Thanks for advice,
Mirek

Answer (score 0):

What you need is object recognition and tracking like YOLO. 
The resources are here. 
https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Then you need to train the model to recognize cars, so you need a bunch of labeled photos where the car bounding box has been already given correctly.

Downstream you want then have the camera connect to a computer and stream the video, have the tracking algorithm recognize the bonding box of the car and, depending on center and size, maneuver the drone accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer.

Comment: Is it possible to access the Mavics object recognition preprocessing and than automatically "identify" car and align the view? I have seen its possible with vision framework on iOS, but do you know how to do this on Android?